Let $ABCDA'B'C'D'$ be a parallelepiped with $AB=10\sqrt{3}, BC=10,CC'=20$. Find the position of the point M, so that the triangle $AMC'$ is isosceles.
the question
Let $ABCDA'B'C'D'$ be a rectangular parallelepiped with $AB=10\sqrt{3}, BC=10,CC'=20$. Find the position of the point $M\in BB'$, so that the triangle $AMC'$ is isosceles.
the idea
drawing

We can easily find $AC'=\sqrt{l^2+L^2+h^2}=20\sqrt{2}$
From here we have to analyse 3 cases:
1)$AM=MC'$
2)$AM=AC'$
3)$MC'=AC'$
FIRST CASE: If $AM=MC'=> AM^2=MC'^2$, then we have by the theorem of pytaghora $MB^2+300=B'M^2+100=> 200=(B'M+MB)*(B'M-MB)$
I don't know what to do forward because we are not sure that $M\in [BB']$ so M can anywhere...
Hope one of you can help me!Thank you!

Hint: 300+25=100+225

@RobinSparrow I know what you mean... that $(B'M+MB)=BB'=20$ and that $B'M-MB=10$ but as I said, we don't know if $M\in [BB']$, so M can be outside of B and B'

Why do you not know that M is on the edge? You are told it is between B and B' in the problem. And going 5 up, of the 20, yields an isosceles triangle.

@RobinSparrow It doesnt say anywhere that it is between B and B'... It says is just on line BB'

Normally we would interpret that problem as limiting M to the edge BB'. Which also renders your 2nd and 3rd cases non-existent, for it is impossible for a segment on a face to be equal to the diagonal of the volume. But the algebra proves that too - that only a single solution exists, on the edge - as John Omelion showed.

I believe that "rectangular parallelepiped" means the same thing as the specific case of a parallelepiped also called a rectangular cuboid. As such, we can use the Pythagorean theorem as you did with the various lengths. Also, each face being a rectangle means that
$$BB' = CC' = 20 \;\to\; B'M = 20 - MB$$
Thus, we have from your equation that
$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
MB^2 + 300 &= B'M^2 + 100 \\
MB^2 + 300 &= (20 - MB)^2 + 100 \\
MB^2 + 300 & = 400 - 40MB + MB^2 + 100 \\
40MB & = 200 \\
MB & = 5
\end{aligned}\end{equation}$$
Note this is the only possible position for $M$. First, the question states that $M \in BB'$, which generally means it's on that line segment. Nonetheless, the equations still apply even if $M \not\in BB'$ but still along the line extending that line segment, since then either $MB \gt 20$ (so $B'M \lt 0$) or $MB \lt 0$. In either case, since the Pythagorean theorem squares the values, any one being negative doesn't cause any issues.

For your other $2$ cases, the procedure is similar. With $AM = AC'$, from the Pythagorean theorem and your result that $AC' = 20\sqrt{2}$, we get
$$AB^2 + MB^2 = AM^2 \;\;\to\;\; 300 + MB^2 = 800 \;\;\to\;\; MB = \pm 10\sqrt{5}$$
However, $-10\sqrt{5}$ indicates $M$ is below $B$, while $10\sqrt{5} \gt 20$ means $M$ would be above $B'$. Thus, both are outside of the $BB'$ line segment, as RobinSparrow's comment indicates. As that comment also suggests, this can be determined from, for any $M$ on the line segment $BB'$, that $AC' \gt AB' \gt MB$ so $AC' \neq MB$.
Finally, for your third case, we get similar results to the above, only with $MB$ replaced with $MB'$ and $300$ (i.e., $AB^2$) replaced with $100$ (i.e., $B'C'^2$), to get $MB' = \pm 10\sqrt{7}$.

Can you look at the above comment...I think we cant assume that $B'M+MB=20$

@IONELABUCIU I looked at your comment, & later noticed it in your question, which is why I updated my answer to try to address it. Note although $MB$ and $MB'$ usually means lengths or distances, i.e., they are non-negative, in the relation $B'M + MB = 20$, we can have one of the values be negative if $M$ is outside of $BB'$. Since the Pythagorean theorem squares the values, being negative doesn't affect them. Also, the calculations done in my second set of equations don't assume or require the values to be any particular sign. As such, they show there is just the one solution of $MB=5$.

Now i understand! Thanks! But what about the other cases?

@IONELABUCIU You're welcome. I'm glad you now understand. However, now I don't understand what you mean by "But what about the other cases". The equations apply to all of the cases, including $M$ being other above $B'$ or below $B$. Since they result in showing there's only the one point $5$ above $B$ which works, then $M$ can only be there, i.e., it can't be outside of the $BB'$ line segment.

I am talking about the cases where $AM=AC'$ or $MC'=AC'$...

@IONELABUCIU Thanks for explaining. I earlier thought you were referring to something else. I've just updated my answer to deal with those other cases, with the results indicating that $M$ would be outside of the $BB'$ line segment so, as RobinSparrow's comment also indicates, there's only one solution on the edge $BB'$ itself.

Shouldnt $MB'=+- 10\sqrt{7}$ in the third case? Correct me if I'm wrong!

@IONELABUCIU You're completely right. Thanks for pointing it out. I've now corrected my mistake.

This is a comment too long for a comment, addressing why there is only one solution for this problem.
Imagine you hold a stick in front of you with both hands. You are to imagine all possible isosceles triangles with the stick as a base, and you are permitted to imagine in 3D. Clearly, the plane that cuts you in half from top to bottom and extends to infinity holds all points that create isosceles triangles on that base. Now, imagine there is a line neither in the plane nor parallel to the plane. That line must cross the plane, and it can only cross once. That is exactly the situation of your problem: the diagonal is the stick, the "line" BB' is the line that must cross the plane. This is the geometric reason for why the algebra comes out as a linear equation, with only a single solution.
So, even had you been given a parallelepiped for which an isosceles on the edge were impossible, there would still have only been a single solution, somewhere on the line containing BB', above or below the parallelepiped.
Hope this helps.
